# Print even odd using thread not giving result

Tags: c++, multithreading

could someone please guide why this code does not give any output.
I am trying to print even and odd simultaneously using threads,conditional variable and mutex.
But on running this is not giving any output on screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>
using namespace std;
condition_variable cv;
mutex mtx;
int i=0;
void
printeven ()
{
  cout << "enter even 1";
  for (; i < 100;)
    {
      cout << "enter even 1";
      unique_lock < mutex > locker (mtx);
      cout << "enter even 2";
      cv.wait (locker);
      cout << "enter even 3";
      cout << "from even " << i << endl;
      i = i + 2;
      cv.notify_all ();
    }
}

void
printodd ()
{
  cout << "enter odd 1";
  for (; i < 100;)
    {
      cout << "enter odd 1";
      unique_lock < mutex > locker (mtx);
      cout << "enter odd 2";
      cv.wait (locker);
      cout << "enter odd 3";
      cout << "from odd " << i << endl;
      i = i + 2;
      cv.notify_all ();
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;

  thread t1 (printeven);
  thread t2 (printodd);
  t1.join ();
  t2.join ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use any debugger. If you pause the program execution, you set the both threads are in cv.wait.

Comment: You have a deadlock.

Comment: First time into the loop, your "odd" thread prints some stuff, and then it calls `cv.wait()`. Now it's waiting. The `wait()` won't return until some other thread notifies `cv`. The "even" thread does the same thing. The main thread calls `t1.join()` after starting the two other threads. `t1.join()` won't return until after the "even" thread has completely finished its task. Now all of your program's threads are waiting. Who is left to deliver a notification?

Comment: Then how to solve this deadlock.

Comment: Have you asked your instructor for hints? It looks like maybe you have not put a lot of thought into the assignment yet. (e.g., How will your program ever print any odd numbers when it only ever increments `i` by twos? How does the first number get printed? How can you ensure that a thread won't call `wait()` if it is delayed and it misses the notification?) I'd say, if you can [explain to the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how the first three numbers get printed, then you're probably on the right track.

Comment: P.S., Regarding "misses the notification," You need to know that if one thread makes a single call to `cv.notify_all()` and another thread _blindly_ calls `cv.wait()`, there is no guarantee that the wait() call will ever return. The problem is, if the notify_all() call happens first, then the notification will be _lost._ The `cv` condition variable will _not_ remember that it was notified. notify_all() only wakes threads that are already waiting.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for guidance.I will learn and practice more.